# Apply various filters using PixiJS

Tags: javascript, html, hue, pixi.js

I am working on various types of filters such as hue, contrast and brightness using pixiJS. I tried following code but it is not working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PixiJS HTMLText</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/6.0.0/cjs/pixi.min.js" integrity="sha512-2UwxAK4j5rLrHpoGjr/cDFg2xQcWOeJsYSs2GrUMccLLDPj4TnhKSmFHR32QLIo6J49TuSZm7Qa9jD+MWo5zUA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  <script>
 var stage = new PIXI.Container();
 
// create a PIXI sprite from an image path
var hawaii = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('http://webgl-workshop.com/assets/e826db271aa3c03c69c4aca1e20abf5b.jpg');
 
// center the sprite anchor point
hawaii.anchor.x = 0;
hawaii.anchor.y = 0;
 
// move the sprite to the center of the canvas
hawaii.position.x = 200;
hawaii.position.y = 200;
 
var blurFilter = new PIXI.filters.BlurFilter();
hawaii.filters = [blurFilter];
 
stage.addChild(hawaii);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where did I do wrong? Is my CDN wrong?

Comment: Is this complete code? If yes then is missing things like `PIXI.Application`, `ticker` or `renderer.render(stage)`. Please try using them and if you still have problem then create jsfiddle or codesandbox etc with example - then we will be able to understand better what is wrong.

Comment: Also please dont use [PIXI.Sprite.fromImage](https://pixijs.download/v5.0.2/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#.fromImage) because it is deprecated.